# Correct way to work with vector of arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stdvector

Could someone tell what is the correct way to work with a vector of arrays?

I declared a vector of arrays (`vector<float[4]>`) but got `error: conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'float [4]' requested` when trying to `resize` it. What is going wrong?

Comment: You can't have a vector of native arrays, because they are neither assignable nor copyable.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You cannot store arrays in a `vector` or any other container.  The type of the elements to be stored in a container (called the container's *value type*) must be both copy constructible and assignable.  Arrays are neither.

You can, however, use an `array` class template, like the one provided by Boost, TR1, and C++0x:

```
std::vector<std::array<double, 4> >
```

(You'll want to replace `std::array` with `std::tr1::array` to use the template included in C++ TR1, or `boost::array` to use [the template from the Boost libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/boost/array.hpp).  Alternatively, you can write your own; it's quite straightforward.)

Comment: The second sentence is no longer true in C++11, but the rest is still correct. The problem in C++11 is that arrays are not [`Erasable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Erasable), at least with the default allocator.

Comment: For requirements on STL containers(post C++11), take a look at this thread, ["Has C++11 changed requirements for elements of STL containers, and how?".](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577881/has-c11-changed-requirements-for-elements-of-stl-containers-and-how)

Comment: https://ideone.com/ENLC68 ?

Comment: Actually one can store arrays in vectors now, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75561253/7325599

Answer (score 12):

Use:

```
vector<vector<float>> vecArray; //both dimensions are open!
```

Comment: vector of vector is not contiguous, in case that is required by the OP.

Answer (score 12):

There is no error in the following piece of code:

```
float arr[4];
arr[0] = 6.28;
arr[1] = 2.50;
arr[2] = 9.73;
arr[3] = 4.364;
std::vector<float*> vec = std::vector<float*>();
vec.push_back(arr);
float* ptr = vec.front();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    printf("%g\n", ptr[i]);
```

**OUTPUT IS:**

6.28

2.5

9.73

4.364

**IN CONCLUSION:**

```
std::vector<double*>
```

is another possibility apart from

```
std::vector<std::array<double, 4>>
```

that James McNellis suggested.

Comment: In your example arr is being dangerously cast to a pointer. If arr goes out of scope while vec still exists an undefined behavior (likely stack overflow) will occur.

Comment: this just made the vector non-copyable.

Comment: You cannot `return` this vector.  Because the pointer will be released. So, the pointer vector is useless.

Answer (score 4):

Every element of your vector is a `float[4]`, so when you resize every element needs to default initialized from a `float[4]`. I take it you tried to initialize with an `int` value like `0`?

Try:

```
static float zeros[4] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
myvector.resize(newsize, zeros);
```

Comment: This (after obvious minor fixes) doesn't compile, for the same reason as given in the accepted answer: it's not valid because plain arrays aren't valid container element types. 1st error from `g++`: `C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:281:63: error: static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from input type`

Answer (score 1):

Since C++11 the only general requirement on the element of a vector is that it satisfies the [*Erasable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Erasable) requirement with the used allocator. It basically requires that the object type can be destroyed through a properly rebound `std::allocator_traits::destroy`.

With the standard allocator `std::allocator`, this requirement was not satisfied before C++20, because `std::allocator::destroy` would try to use a simple (pseudo-)destructor call which is well-formed only for class and scalar types, not for array types.

Since C++20 `std::allocator`'s `destroy` is defaulted through `std::allocator_traits` to use `std::destroy_at` and `std::destroy_at` is extended to support array types by calling itself recursively on the array elements. So the *Erasable* requirement is now fulfilled with array types and it is not generally forbidden to use array types in `std::vector` with the default allocator anymore.

However, when actually constructing elements in the vector, the vector must use the allocator's `construct`, which was also defaulted with C++20 to use `std::construct_at`. Unfortunately `std::construct_at` doesn't work with arrays, which is probably unintentional (see open [LWG issue 3436](https://wg21.link/lwg3436)). So currently it is not possible to construct any elements in such a vector with the default allocator and the only way to use `std::vector<float[4]>` is to construct an empty instance.

Even when this issue is resolved, there is however almost no use for such a vector. The only thing one can do with it is constructing an instance with a given number of value-initialized elements and then operate on this fixed-size vector's elements. None of the modifiers can be used because they require some form of copying or moving of the element type, which isn't possible for array types. Such a vector can be moved and swapped, but not copied.