# Should (in C++11) std::vector::resize(size_type) work for the default constructible value_type int[4]?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, default-constructor

In C++11, there are two versions of `std::vector::resize()`:

```
void resize( size_type count );
void resize( size_type count, const value_type& value);
```

I understand (as suggested by one of the comments to one of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184828/compiler-error-with-c-stdvector-of-array)) that the first requires `value_type` to be default constructible, while the second requires it to be copy constructible. However, (gcc 4.7.0)

```
using namespace std;
typedef int block[4];
vector<block> A;
static_assert(is_default_constructible<block>::value,";-("); //  does not fire
A.resize(100);                                               //  compiler error
```

So either my understanding was wrong or gcc is buggy. Which?

Comment: Use this block definition: `struct block { int arr[4]; };`

Comment: possible duplicate of [compiler error with C++ std::vector of array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184828/compiler-error-with-c-stdvector-of-array)

Comment: @PiotrNycz : As opposed to `std::array<int, 4>`?

Comment: @ildjarn Why opposed? It is more or less the same... Due to my job "bad conditions" I am still in C++03 - so I am still thinking in C++03 ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The requirement (23.3.6.3:10) on `vector.resize(n)` being well-formed is that `T` should be *`CopyInsertable`*, i.e. that the following should be well-formed (23.2.1:13):

```
allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, v);
```

where `A` is the allocator type of the vector, `m` is the allocator, `p` is of type `T *` and `v` is of type `T`.

As you can discover from 20.6.8.2:5, this is invalid for array types in the general case as it is equivalent to calling

```
::new(static_cast<void *>(p))block(v);
```

which is invalid for array types (arrays cannot be initialized by parentheses).

---

Actually, you're correct that g++ has a bug; it should always be possible to work around the issue with *`CopyInsertable`* by providing an appropriate allocator, but g++ fails to allow this:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T, int n> struct ArrayAllocator: std::allocator<T[n]> {
    void construct(T (*p)[n], T (&v)[n]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            ::new(static_cast<void *>(p + i)) T{v[i]};
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int[4], ArrayAllocator<int, 4>> c;
    c.resize(100);  // fails

    typedef ArrayAllocator<int, 4> A;
    A m;
    int (*p)[4] = 0, v[4];
    std::allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, v); // works
}
```

---

Another bug is in the standard itself; 20.9.4.3:3 specifies `std::is_default_constructible<T>`  as equivalent to `std::is_constructible<T>`, where 20.9.4.3:6 specifies `std::is_constructible<T, Args...>` as the well-formedness criterion on `T t(std::declval<Args>()...)`, which is valid for array types (as @Johannes Schaub-litb points out, array types can be initialised with *`(zero-pack-expansion)`*).  However, 17.6.3.1:2 requires for `DefaultConstructible` in addition that `T()` be well-formed, which is not the case for an array type `T` but is not checked by `std::is_default_constructible`.

Comment: somebody should file a bug report here.

Comment: First I failed to understand your `T t()`. I guess it is important to mention that it is the result of a `T t(zero pack expansion)`. Otherwise it really is difficult to see what you mean by "variable-definition context". But `T t(zero pack expansion)` *is* valid if `T` is an array type and the element types  can be value initialized. Only `T()` is ill-formed if `T` is an array type.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb thanks, looks like this part is a bug in the standard's definition of `std::is_default_constructible`.

Comment: i asked daniel kruegler and he said he already works on a simila thing (fixing the definition of DefaultConstrictible for aggregates). He agrees with me that the result of the trait is more expected and that the language should probably be fixed to allow `ArrayType()` (especially since `ArrayType{}` is allowed aswell). I trust in him that he takes the appropriate actions.

Answer (score 0):

I found this discussion after I ran into a similar problem with resize() not working for a default-constructible type. It seems like the gcc vector implementation is incorrect.

FYI, I filed a bug against gcc:
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64147