# type requirements for std::vector<type>

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11, allocation, stdvector

I am still confused about the requirements for a type to be used with a `std::vector` in C++11, but this may be caused by a buggy compiler (gcc 4.7.0). This code:

```
struct A {
  A() : X(0) { std::cerr<<" A::A(); this="<<this<<'\n'; }
  int X;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<A> a;
  a.resize(4);
}
```

works fine and produces the expected output, indicating that the default ctor (explicitly given) is called (and not an implicit copy ctor). However, if I add a deleted copy ctor to the class, viz

```
struct A {
  A() : X(0) { std::cerr<<" A::A(); this="<<this<<'\n'; }
  A(A const&) = delete;
  int X;
};
```

gcc 4.7.0 does not compile, but tries to use the deleted ctor. Is that correct behaviour or a bug? If the former, how to get the code working?

Comment: Please elaborate on "expected output".  How many lines of output are produced?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<del>The C++11 standard does indeed require `CopyInsertable` as others have pointed out.  However this is a bug in the C++11 standard.  This has since been corrected in [N3376](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf) to `MoveInsertable` and `DefaultInsertable`.</del>

The `vector<T, A>::resize(n)` member function requires `MoveInsertable` and `DefaultInsertable`.  These roughly translate to `DefaultConstructible` and `MoveConstructible` when the allocator `A` uses the default `construct` definitions.

The following program compiles using clang/libc++:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  A() : X(0) { std::cerr<<" A::A(); this="<<this<<'\n'; }
  A(A&&) = default;
  int X;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<A> a;
  a.resize(4);
}
```

and for me prints out:

```
 A::A(); this=0x7fcd634000e0
 A::A(); this=0x7fcd634000e4
 A::A(); this=0x7fcd634000e8
 A::A(); this=0x7fcd634000ec
```

If you remove the move constructor above and replace it with a deleted copy constructor, `A` is no longer `MoveInsertable`/`MoveConstructible` as move construction then attempts to use the deleted copy constructor, as correctly demonstrated in the OP's question.

Comment: Note however that libstdc++ does not respect the allocator template argument; see my answer.

Comment: I had the same output, but am still confused, as the default ctor is called for every object. So the move ctor does not seem to be called at all. Note that the result remains the same if the move ctor is replaced with a copy ctor: it is never called, but required by the implementation of `std::vector::resize()`.

Comment: I've upvoted ecatmur's correct answer to your question at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12259886/576911

Comment: I suspect that not having the default ctor is fine as long one avoids calls to `resize()`. Also note that it is necessary to provide a copy ctor in case one plans to use the vector fill constructor: `std::vector<A> a(10,A());`.

Answer (score 3):

In C++11, the requirements depend on the operations performed. In the case of `std::vector<T>::resize()`, the requirement on `T` is that it be [`CopyInsertable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyInsertable) into the vector.

From §23.3.6.3

> `void resize(size_type sz);`
>
> ....
>
> Requires: `T` shall be `CopyInsertable` into *this.

Answer (score 2):

To use a class in a vector it should have a copy constructor/assignment operator or a noexcept move constructor/assignment operator. GCC is quite correct not to compile your example which doesn't have any of these.

How would you except the vector to do anything without being able to copy or move what it contains?

The reason that the first example works is that since you didn't define any copy or move constructors or assignment operators, you get the defaults. In the second example, since you explicitly deleted the copy constructor, you don't get any automatically generated constructors or assignment operators.

Comment: That is actually wrong. Deleting the copy constructor should have no effect on the assignment operator, and the class has a user defined default constructor.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the move ctor. Indeed, if I give that (using `=default`) but `delete` the copy ctor, it works correct! **EDIT** I re-interpret your assignment operator as constructor, to correct your mistake.

Comment: @juanchopanza deleting the copy ctor does prevent the generation of a move assignment operator. It leaves the copy assignment operator for legacy reasons, but any program that uses it is highly suspect.

Comment: But your claim that you don't get automatically generated assignment operators is incorrect. You get a copy assignment operator, whether it makes sense or not.

Answer (score 2):

[On ideone](http://ideone.com/akPp3), I see one call to the default constructor.  But four objects are being created, the others have to be constructed somehow.  Actually, a prototype object is default constructed and then copied four times.

The C++11 Standard (section 23.3.6.3) says that "value initialized" objects will be inserted, but also requires that the type is copyable:

> `void resize(size_type  sz);`
>
> - Effects:  If `sz <= size()`, equivalent to `erase(begin() +  sz, end());`.  If `size() < sz`, appends `sz - size()` value-initialized elements to the sequence.
> - Requires: `T` shall be `CopyInsertable` into `*this`.

There's no compiler bug here; it is your code which is wrong.

Comment: Ben, interestingly, my output differs from the one you got with gcc 4.5.4 on ideone: I get:  `A::A() on this=0x603010
 A::A() on this=0x603014
 A::A() on this=0x603018
 A::A() on this=0x60301c`, i.e. the default ctor is called 4 times, not just once and then objects are copied from that. This is a significant difference ...

Comment: This may be a spec defect, however. Note that the `vector` constructor that takes only a size only requires `DefaultConstructible`. There's no reason for `resize` to require `CopyInsertable`; only `DefaultConstructible` and whatever reallocation might require.

Comment: @NicolBolas So you're implying that gcc is buggy?

Comment: @Walter: A *spec defect* is not a bug in software. It's a bug in the *spec*.

Answer (score 1):

`void resize(size_type)` requires `CopyInsertable`, which means that an allocator should be able to construct-copy the type:

```
::new((void*)p)A(A());
```

This means that a copy-constructor is required.  You should be able to bypass this with a custom allocator:

```
struct Allocator: public std::allocator<A> {
  void construct(A *, const A &) { }
};
```

However libstdc++ does not respect this; see [Should (in C++11) std::vector::resize(size_type) work for the default constructible value_type int[4]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192895/should-in-c11-stdvectorresizesize-type-work-for-the-default-constructi/12193149#12193149)

Comment: Why not `::new((void*)p)A();` instead of `::new((void*)p)A(A());`, I do not understand benefit of `A(A())` over `A()`...

Comment: @PiotrNycz that's from the default implementation of `iterator_traits::construct` for copy construction.