# strange behaviour of std::vector::resize() with gcc 4.7.0

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11, allocation, stdvector

I'm still confused about the behaviour of `std::vector::resize()`. Consider the following code (see also [type requirements for std::vector<type>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251368/type-requirements-for-stdvectortype))

```
struct A {
  A() : X(0) { std::cerr<<" A::A(); this="<<this<<'\n'; }
  A(A const&) { assert(0); }  // is required but doesn't fire in vector::resize
  int X;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<A> a;
  a.resize(4);        // would not compile without A::A(A const&) or A::A(A&&)
}
```

Without `A::A(A const&)` or `A::A(A&&)`, the line with `a.resize(4);` doesn't compile. However, that constructor is never called: the `assert(0)` doesn't fire! Can somebody explain that to me?

My interpretation is that the presence of either of these constructors is required by the template magic of `allocator_traits<>` (used by `std::vector::resize()`), but is actually never called. However, why would you require the presence of a method if you're not calling it?

Comment: There's nothing in there to copy? **Edit** On checking, the assert kills it for me... Are you compiling out the assert ( `-DNDEBUG` if I remember correctly)?

Comment: Actually, I wasn't compiling with `--std=c++0x`. With that, I see the normal ctor called 4 times. Have a little look here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest revision of the standard ([n3376](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf)) says:

> 12 - If `size() < sz`,
>   appends `sz - size()` default-inserted elements to the sequence.
>   13 - Requires: `T` shall be `MoveInsertable` and `DefaultInsertable` into `*this`.

The implication is that `MoveInsertable` is required for any reallocation that might occur, while `DefaultInsertable` is required for the actual appending.  So your copy or move constructor will fire only if your vector already contains elements and needs to be reallocated.

Indeed, if we write:

```
std::vector<A> a;
a.resize(1);
assert(!a.empty() && a.capacity() < 4);
a.resize(4);
```

then the copy- or move-constructor of `A` is called, and your assert is triggered.

Answer (score 3):

In order to `resize` a vector, existing elements must be placed into the newly-allocated chunk of memory if the vector didn't have enough space to hold the elements required by the new size. This is done by copy-constructing them. So you must have a copy constructor to resize a vector. In this case, there are no existing elements, so the copy constructor is not called. But it still must be present.

Comment: +1 for the correct reasoning, though ecatmur's answer is more precise

Answer (score 0):

In your example, when you call vector::resize() method,  the constructor is called instead of the copy constructor. That is why you do not see assert being triggered.

As for why you need the copy-constructor (and move constructor, which you haven't defined and declared), is that the template types have to be Copy-constructable and move-constructable. [container.requirements.general]/15 defines the requirements for container's type :

```
— T is DefaultInsertable into X means that the following expression is well-formed: allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p);
— An element of X is default-inserted if it is initialized by evaluation of the expression allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p);
where p is the address of the uninitialized storage for the element allocated within X.
— T is CopyInsertable into X means that the following expression is well-formed: allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, v);
— T is MoveInsertable into X means that the following expression is well-formed: allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, rv);
— T is EmplaceConstructible into X from args , for zero or more arguments args, means that the following expression is well-formed: allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, args);
— T is Erasable from X means that the following expression is well-formed: allocator_traits<A>::destroy(m, p);
```

Comment: I knew that, you don't answer my question

Comment: @Walter From your question : *Without A::A(A const&) or A::A(A&&), the line with a.resize(4); doesn't compile. However, that constructor is never called: the assert(0) doesn't fire! Can somebody explain that to me?*

Comment: I think you should highlight your edits, as otherwise the comments seem odd.