# Exception safety of std::vector implementation shipped with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-2015, stl, c++14

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
struct X
{
    int state;
    X() : state(0) {};
    X(int x) : state(x) {};
    X(X const& y) noexcept : state(1) {}
    X(X&& y) noexcept(false) : state(y.state != 8 ? 2 : throw 1) 
    { y.state = 0; }
    X& operator =(X const&) = default;
    X& operator =(X&&) = default;
};
int main() {
    std::vector<X> a;
    a.reserve(2u);
    a.emplace_back(6);
    a.emplace_back(8);
    try { 
        // ####
        std::cout << 'A' << a.front().state << a.back().state;
    }
    catch (...) 
    { 
        std::cout << 'B' << a.front().state << a.back().state;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

At position `// ####` different statements may be employed, each giving different output on g++/clang++ versus msvc.

```
    statement               g++     msvc    expected

1   a.resize(10u, X{});     A11     B08     A11
2   X b; a.push_back(b);    A11     B08     A11
3   a.emplace_back(1);      A11     B08     A11
```

So, why do I expect `A11` in all cases here?

**1: `a.resize(10u, X{});`**

[vector.capacity], 16/17 of n4140 and n4606 say about `void resize(size_type sz, const T& c);`

> Requires: `T` shall be `CopyInsertable` into `*this`.
>
> Remarks: If an exception is thrown there are no effects.

Thus, if the compiler must guarantee that a full rollback in case of an exception is possible ("no effects") it must either copy the elements or can only move if the move is noexcept because moving has an immediate effect on the elements which cannot be rolled back (which would only be necessary if moving would throw which in turn is not the case for noexcept move constructors).

Therefore, I'd expect `A11` as output (or `B68` if the copy constructor throws).

**2: `X b; a.push_back(b);`**

**3: `a.emplace_back(1);`**

[vector.modifiers], 1 of n4140 and n4606 say:

> If an exception is thrown while inserting a single element at the end and `T` is `CopyInsertable` or `is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value` is `true`, there are no effects.

Again the standard requires "no effect" in case of an exception when the type is "CopyInsertable" (X is CopyInsertible). -> move_if_noexcept!

My interpretation of those mandates would be that `A11` is the expected output (or in other terms, that a conformant std::vector shouldn't move its elements unless moving is noexcept or copying is impossible).

I tried to find some information on the VS SL but only found a blog post '[VS 2015 Update 2’s STL is C++17-so-far Feature Complete](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/01/22/vs-2015-update-2s-stl-is-c17-so-far-feature-complete/)' on the VS blog suggests that the VS standard library implementation is "feature complete" where I don't get whether this is supposed to claim standard compliance.

*Note: I doubt that I'm the first to spot that VS incorrectly moves its elements when it should actually copy them - if anyone has a connect issue or SO-question, don't refrain from pointing to it.*

So the question is: Is there a specific reason for the behaviour in MSVC (i.e. performance implications other than copy vs. move or anything) or is this a bug?

Comment: Isn't `:state(state != 8 ? 2 : throw 1)` causing UB as you access `state` before it is initialized? Did you mean to write `X(X&& x) noexcept(false) : state(x.state != 8 ? 2 : throw 1) { }`

Comment: @SimonKraemer: indeed :)

Comment: Looks like a bug. You can check the vector implementation to see how its done. In libstd++, they have a `__move_if_noexcept` (or something similar) to copy instead of move where move would throw.

Comment: @Arunmu: As far as I can tell, MSVC uses `std::memmove` for trivial types or `_Al.construct(_Unfancy(_Dest), _STD move(*_First));` in the general case where it should rather be `move_if_noexcept`.

Comment: Hmm, not sure is this is a bug or not. According to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12251704/4181011) the type used with `std:vector`must be MoveConstructible which seems to be defined as `T u = rv; u is equivalent to the value of rv before the construction` (see the linked document for more examples) which your `state` doesn't fulfill. Also the exception isn't thrown while `inserting a single element at the end`.

Comment: @SimonKraemer It's highly unlikely that clang and g++ gets it wrong and visual c++ right :).

Comment: @Arunmu I am not saying that but maybe it's just unspecified behaviour as the preconditions are not fullfilled?

Comment: @SimonKraemer: The requirements for `T` depend on the used member functions of `std::vector`. Furthermore, my type is `MoveInsertible` (which doesn't mean that move insertion may not throw but rather that a constructor binding an rvalue must be present). I broke the example down into three where I give the requirements for each function.

Comment: @Pixelchemist Just saw your update. That does look like a bug.

Comment: Technically speaking, this class doesn't seem either CopyInsertable or MoveInsertable to me, since it fails to meet the required postcondition for the operations.

Comment: In any event, http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ prints `A11` for all cases.

Comment: @T.C.: Currently under maintenance - but the webcompiler isn't using the current stable release anyway, is it?

Comment: @T.C.: If I remove the `state` stuff and just print something in the move constructor the result remains the same. The objects are being moved in absence of a noexcept move constructor - if any of them throws the mandated rollback is impossible.