# Why has the std::vector::resize signature been changed in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, resize

What are the reasons behind the change in `std::vector::resize` from the pre-C++11:

```
void resize( size_type count, T value = T() );
```

to the compatible C++11 form:

```
void resize( size_type count );
void resize( size_type count, const value_type& value);
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Paragraph C.2.12 of the Annex C (Compatibility) to the C++11 Standard specifies:

> *Change*: Signature changes: `resize`
>
> *Rationale*: **Performance, compatibility with move semantics**.
>
> *Effect on original feature*: For `vector`, `deque`, and `list` the fill value passed to resize is now passed by
>   reference instead of by value, and an additional overload of resize has been added. Valid C++ 2003 code
>   that uses this function may fail to compile with this International Standard.

The old `resize()` function was copy-constructing new elements from `value`. This makes it impossible to use `resize()` when the elements of the vector are default-constructible but non-copyable (you may want to move-assign them later on). This explains the "*Compatibility with move semantics*" rationale.

Moreover, it may be slow if you do not want any copy to occur, just new elements to be default-constructed. Also, the `value` parameter is passed by value in the C++03 version, which incurs in the overhead of an unnecessary copy ([as mentioned by TemplateRex in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17002723/1932150)). This explains the "*Performance*" rationale.

Comment: Nice. Now, can you find an example where this would break existing code?

Comment: @KonradRudolph It should be backwards compatible. The first C++11 overload is equivalent to not providing a 2nd argument in C++98, and the second C++11 overload only requires constructible, which C++98 already required for resizing. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @TemplateRex The standard quote in this answer explicitly says that this isn’t the case: “Valid C++ 2003 code that uses this function may fail to compile”.

Comment: @KonradRudolph maybe array types can break: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12193149/819272

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I can't think of a good example right now. If legacy code that called `resize()` with just one argument counted on the fact that the additional elements will be copy-constructed from a default-constructed value rather than being default-constructed, then this may matter. But again, that would likely be dumb code. IOW, I can't come up with a good example.

Comment: @AndyProwl Doesn’t the ’03 standard explicitly say that programs cannot rely on side-effects of cctor due to copy elision or is that only allowed in the specific contexts of direct variable initialisation and return-value optimisation?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I'm pretty sure I was brainfarting, but the copy-construction of the vector's elements from `T` is not a context where elision could be performed. Perhaps TemplateRex has a point though

Comment: an easy example of a breaking change would be code that stores a pointer to the `resize` method. `void(vector<T>::*)(size_t,T) ptr = &vector<T>::resize` would compile in C++03 (modulo typos)

Answer (score 17):

One reason is that default arguments are always passed, i.e. copied in this case. Doing

```
 my_vector.resize(1000000)
```

would copy 1 million `T` objects.

In C++11 you now have a choice between copying a user-provided value or default-inserting (i.e. constructing) elements in-place, using the `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::construct()` function. This allows resizing of `vector` with elements that are CopyInsertable but not Copyable.

Note that this change has been done to all sequence containers having a `resize()` member (`vector`, `deque`, `forward_list` and `list`), but not for `std::string` which didn't have a default value argument to begin with.

**Update**: apart from the Annex to the current Standard cited by @AndyProwl, the [original defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#679) by @HowardHinnant also clarifies:

> The problem with passing T by value is that it can be significantly
>   more expensive than passing by reference. The converse is also true,
>   however when it is true it is usually far less dramatic (e.g. for
>   scalar types).
>
> Even with move semantics available, passing this parameter by value
>   can be expensive. Consider for example vector>:

```
std::vector<int> x(1000); std::vector<std::vector<int>> v; ...
v.resize(v.size()+1, x);
```

> In the pass-by-value case, x is copied once
>   to the parameter of resize. And then internally, since the code can
>   not know at compile time by how much resize is growing the vector, x
>   is usually copied (not moved) a second time from resize's parameter
>   into its proper place within the vector.
>
> With pass-by-const-reference, the x in the above example need be
>   copied only once. In this case, x has an expensive copy constructor
>   and so any copies that can be saved represents a significant savings.
>
> If we can be efficient for push_back, we should be efficient for
>   resize as well. The resize taking a reference parameter has been coded
>   and shipped in the CodeWarrior library with no reports of problems
>   which I am aware of.

Comment: C++11: Power to the developers! We give *you* the right to choose which objects to copy!