# Which is most costly in C++, remove last element or resize of a vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, resize

Which operation is most costly in C++?
1. Resize of a vector (decrease size by 1)
2. Remove last element in vector

Comment: Neither, no reallocating will happen in optimized library.

Comment: @deviantfan I don't think any re-allocation will happen if resizing to a smaller size. I think it is even not allowed.

Comment: @deviantfan How does it depend on implementation? I think you are spreading confusion here (note there is no `resize_to_fit`.)

Comment: Yeah, it´s shrink_to_fit ... I´m confused myself. Please ignore my comments here (or I remove them now)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector which essentially quotes the Standard:

```
void pop_back();
```

> Removes the last element of the container.
>   No iterators or references except for `back()` and `end()` are invalidated.

```
void resize( size_type count );
```

> Resizes the container to contain count elements. If the current size
>   is greater than count, the container is reduced to its first count
>   elements as if **by repeatedly calling `pop_back()`**.

So in this case, calling `resize(size() - 1)` should be equivalent to calling `pop_back()`. However, calling `pop_back()` is the right thing to do as it **expresses your intent**.

**NOTE**: the answer is reflecting the [**changed interface**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17002690/819272) of C++11's `std::vector::resize()`, which used to contain a hidden default argument which was being copied around (and which may or may not have been optimized away).

Comment: Also, `pop_back()` does not invalidate iterators or references, so no re-allocations can take place.

Comment: @juanchopanza sure, but shrinking resizes also don't invalidate anything because they are equivalent to a sequence of pop_backs. Updated with the full quote though. Tnx!

Comment: Right. `resize()` to smaller sizes is described in terms of the teo-iterator version of `erase`, and that can only invalidate iterators or references to the elements being erased. So `resize`, `pop_back` or `erase` should be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion they are equivalent. The both operations remove the last element and decrease the size.:)

According to the C++ Standard

> void resize(size_type sz); 12 Effects: If sz <= size(), **equivalent** to
>   calling pop_back() size() - sz times

So they are simply equivalent according to my opinion and the point of view of the Standard.:)

Also if to consider member function `erase` instead of `pop_back` (in fact they do the same in this case) then according to the same Standard

> 4 Complexity: The destructor of T is called the number of times equal
>   to the number of the elements  erased, but the move assignment
>   operator of T is called the number of times equal to the number of 
>   elements in the vector after the erased elements.

As there are no move operations for the last element then the cost is the same.

Comment: @user2899162 Do you mean the wrong comments, or the right ones? :-)

Comment: @user2899162 Well, do you know such an implementation instead of your bla, bla, bla?

Comment: Note in the current standard `resize` to a smaller size is expressed in terms of `erase`, but the same conclusions hold: there are no re-allocations.