# Does a vector<std::array<float,10>> of size 5 result in 50 contiguous floats?

Tags: c++

*The suggested duplicates do not directly answer this particular question.* One of them just addresses the contiguity of the elements of vector without talking about array while the other discusses the use of array instead of float[N] without talking about contiguitiness (is that a word?).

Does a `vector<std::array<float,10>>` of `size()`=5 result in 50 contiguous floats in memory, such that a pointer to the `vector[0]` element points to the start of this stretch of memory?

Comment: well, there would be no way to fill that vector with anything, so that questions point is kind of moot.

Comment: It's not a duplicate - the other question is about scalars being placed in contiguous regions; the OP asks about a vector of arrays.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight [The second duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612273/correct-way-to-work-with-vector-of-arrays) addresses the problem of putting arrays in vectors. One should use `std::array<float,10>` in this case. The floats are continuous, which is discussed in [the first duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849168/are-stdvector-elements-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous).

Comment: @leemes That's a much better duplicate, thanks for finding it!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight He didn't find it, I did :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Well, the first duplicate discusses if the memory is continuous, which is the question. The problem that a vector of arrays is not really possible is another question ;) But of course, the answer that it is continuous only helps if one already has chosen the correct array type, namely `std::array` over raw arrays.

Comment: @trojanfoe True. So I `std::forward("thanks")`. ;)

Comment: @leemes  I have edited the question, which still applies and doesn't seem to be answered in the "duplicates"

Comment: @Fellowshee: It is answered there. Just combine them. 1) your construct is not possible 2) vectors memory is contiguous.

Comment: @PlasmaHH. Wrong. I can make an inference that my assumption is correct, but since a vector of another container is not guaranteed to be contiguous, and none of those answers addresses my exact vector, then my question is valid, though I agree it is similar.

Comment: @Fellowshee: I would be intrested to see a full compiling code sample using your construct.

Comment: "[The suggested duplicates do not directly answer this particular question.]" -- please tell us why they don't

Comment: @JanDvorak: Because one of them just addresses the contiguity of the elements of `vector` without talking about `array` while the other discusses the use of `array<float,N>` instead of `float[N]` without talking about _contiguitiness_ (is that a word?).

Comment: @rodrigo thanks, and I believe the word is _contiguity_ maybe? cheers

Comment: So the actual question to be answered in addition to the supposed duplicates is, *is a `std::array<float,10>` guaranteed to store 10 contiguous `float`s and only those (without any additional padding or alignment issues) and thus layout compatible to a `float[10]`?*, which *rodrigo* seems to answer -> +1 for reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. At least if you could create one.

Arrays are not copyable in C++ so you will have a hard time trying to insert them in the array.

UPDATE: Yes, `vector<array<float, N>>` has the contiguous memory because `vector` has that requirement and `array` is layout compatible with native arrays, so no padding or anything that may be in the middle.

Note that `vector<vector<float>>` will **not** have contiguous memory, because each vector has additional fields.

Comment: "because each vector has additional fields" Actually, this is not the reason. The reason is because the vector's actual data is stored somewhere else (indirectly), so their contents can be spread over the whole memory, not only separated by their "overhead". Vectors are more or less a pointer to their data + some extra information (I guess size + allocated size).