# What is a good way of dynamically expanding an array to import data?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, heap-memory, deque

I am looking for help in creating a dynamically expanding array to import data from a .csv file.  I do not want to have to see how large the file is and edit the variable in the source code/prompt the user, I just want the data to be imported then manipulated in various ways.  First, my code as-is:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

//declare variables and arrays
long rows = 170260;
int cols = 5;
double **rawData = new double*[rows]; //on heap because of size
for(long pi = 0; pi < rows; ++pi) //create an array of pointers
{
         rawData[pi] = new double[cols];
}
char buff[200];
double deltaT;
double carDeltaV;
double *carV = new double[rows]; //on heap because of size

//import raw data
std::cout << "Importing filedata.csv...";

std::ifstream rawInput("filedata.csv");

for(long r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
{
      rawInput.getline(buff, 200);
      std::stringstream ss(buff);

      for(int c = 0; c < cols; ++c) 
      {
            ss.getline(buff, 40, ',');
            rawData[r][c] = atof(buff);
      }
}

std::cout << "Done." << std::endl;

//create speed matrix
carV[0] = 0;

std::cout << std::endl << "Creating speed matrix...";

for (long i = 1; i < rows; ++i) 
{

    deltaT = rawData[i][0] - rawData[i-1][0];
    carDeltaV = rawData[i-1][3] * deltaT;
    carV[i] = carDeltaV + carV[i-1];
}

std::cout << "Done." << std::endl;

//write data to csv file
std::cout << std::endl << "Writing data to file...";

std::ofstream outputData;
outputData.open("outputdata.csv");

for(long r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
{
         outputData << rawData[r][0] << "," << rawData[r][3]/.00981 << ",";
         outputData << carV[r] << std::endl;
}

outputData.close();
std::cout << "Done." << std::endl;

//delete pointers
std::cout << std::endl << "Clearing memory...";

for(long pj = 0; pj < rows; ++pj)
{
         delete [] rawData[pj];
}
delete [] rawData;
delete [] carV;

std::cout << "Done." << std::endl;

std::cin.get();
return 0;

}
```

Note:  The amount of colums will always be 5.  The rows are my unknown.  An example of what I will be importing can be seen below:

```
0.001098633,0.011430004,0.002829004,-0.004371409,0.00162947
0.001220703,0.00606778,0.001273052,0.003497127,0.002359922
0.001342773,0.003104446,-0.000848701,0.012385657,-0.008119254
```

There is more to it, but this should be enough to understand what I am trying to accomplish.  I have read up on vectors a bit, but the concept of a vector-of-vectors is a bit confusing to me, and I have tried to implement it with no success.  Also, I read that a deque might be what I am looking for?  I have no experience with those, and it seems to me that it may be overkill for my application since I am only appending in one direction to an array of data.

Disclaimer:  I am pretty much a novice at C++, so if there are any concepts that you feel would be above my level of skill please let me know so I can read up on it.

Any advice?

Edit:  By request, this is how I tried to do this with vectors.

```
std::vector<double> rawDataRow;
std::vector< std::vector<double> > rawDataMatrix;

//import raw data loop
std::ifstream rawInput("test.csv");

for(int i = 1; i > 0; ) {
          rawInput.getline(buff, 200);
          std::stringstream ss(buff);

          for(int c = 0; c < cols; ++c) {
                  ss.getline(buff, 40, ',');
                  value = atof(buff);
                  rawDataRow.push_back(value);

                  std::cout << rawDataRow[0] << std::endl;
          }
          timeDiff = timeAfter - timeBefore;
          timeBefore = timeAfter;
          timeAfter = rawDataRow[0];

          rawDataMatrix.push_back(rawDataRow);
}
```

where "i" would be set to 0 at eof.

Comment: Use a `std::vector<T>` with a suitable type `T` to hold the elements and use `vector.push_back(value)` to append each record. The class will take care of growning as needed.

Comment: Can you show your code with vectors?

Comment: Are you only using the first and fourth column?  If so, you can save effort by not converting string to double the other three values per row.

Comment: @DietmarKühl That is what I tried to implement, but was not able to do.  How would this be handled in 2D?

Comment: Actually `deque` sounds like it's perfect for this application precisely because you're only appending at the end.

Comment: `vector <vector <double>> my2dvector;`

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis I am using every column, but did not show what I am doing with that data for clarity.

Comment: @AntonPoznyakovskiy I edited how I tried to do it with vectors.  I am not sure what you mean by access elements of my table randomly.  I will always need to refer back to the data in the vector, but I will always start from the beginning and run through until the end.

Comment: In your vector implementation, `rawDataRow` keeps the data after each iteration of the for loop. Consider `rawDataRow.clear()` after pushing. Or define it inside the loop.

Comment: @AntonPoznyakovskiy Can I create an array that (temporarily) stores the contents of the row, then store that array's contents to a vector?  Or must I do this with a vector? (are vector-of-arrays possible? or can it only be a vector-of-vectors?)

Answer (score 0):

To sum up the questions that have arisen in the discussion:

You cannot have a vector of arrays, see there: [Correct way to work with vector of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612273/correct-way-to-work-with-vector-of-arrays) You can have a vector of pointers to arrays. However, at this point I wouldn't mess with all the memory handling.

The best is if you keep your code with vectors, except that you should put the definition of `rawDataRow` inside the loop to purge its contents on every iteration.

```
std::vector< std::vector<double> > rawDataMatrix;

//import raw data loop
std::ifstream rawInput("test.csv");

for(int i = 1; i > 0; ) {
      std::vector<double> rawDataRow;
      rawInput.getline(buff, 200);
      std::stringstream ss(buff);

      // do the rest
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are making your life just too hard. The key realization is, however, that you **always** need to check input **before** using it in some form. Once you do that things fall into place easily.

To conveniently deal with input of a line, the first thing I'd define is this simple manipulator which would ignore a comma:

```
std::istream& comma(std::istream& in) {
    if ((in >> std::ws).peek() == ',') {
        in.ignore(); // the happy case: just skip over the comma
    }
    else if (!in.peek() == std::char_traits<char>::eof()) {
        in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit); // unhappy: not the end and not a comma
    }
    return in;
}
```

With this in place, it is fairly easy to read lines and split them into cells:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> result;
for (std::string line; std::getline(in, line); ) {
    std::istringstream lin(line);
    std::vector<double> row;
    for (double d; d >> lin >> comma; ) {
        row.push_back(d);
    }
    if (!lin.eof()) {
        in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    }
    std::result.push_back(row);
}
if (!in.eof()) {
    std::cout << "there was an input error\n";
}
else {
    // result contains the result of reading...
}
```

I haven't tested the code and I'd guess there are typos somewhere but the general approach should just work...

Comment: I was definitely making the problem more difficult than it needed to be.  With the help of you and the other comments I was able to learn more and (I hope) become a better programmer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should split your program into three parts:

1. Reading data from an input file
2. Processing the data
3. Writing data to an output file

Your main program should basically look like this:

```
int main() {
  vector<InputRecord> data = read_from_csv("filedata.csv");
  vector<double> speeds = compute_speeds(data);
  write_to_csv("result.csv", data, speeds);
  return 0;
}
```

Now you need to define what an `InputRecord` is. You said that it’s an array of 5 doubles, but that’s not the best description. It should be more like this:

```
struct InputRecord {
  double timestamp;
  double field2;
  double field3;
  double location;
  double field5;
};
```

Using this data structure, you can write `data[0].timestamp` instead of `data[0][0]`, which means you don’t need the comments anymore.

Here is the complete code that I wrote for this task. It does a similar thing to yours and should be good as a starting point. Note that this code doesn’t do explicit memory management at all.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::string;
using std::vector;

struct InputRecord {
  double timestamp;
  double field2;
  double field3;
  double location;
  double field5;
};

vector<InputRecord> read_from_csv(const char *filename) {
  std::ifstream in(filename);
  vector<InputRecord> data;

  if (!in.is_open()) {
    throw std::ios_base::failure(string()
        + "cannot open input file \"" + filename + "\".");
  }

  string line;
  while (std::getline(in, line)) {
    InputRecord rec;
    char end_of_line;
    if (std::sscanf(line.c_str(), "%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf%c",
        &rec.timestamp, &rec.field2, &rec.field3,
        &rec.location, &rec.field5, &end_of_line) != 5) {
      throw std::ios_base::failure(string()
          + "input file \"" + filename + "\" "
          + "contains invalid data: \"" + line + "\"");
    }
    data.push_back(rec);
  }
  if (in.bad()) {
    throw std::ios_base::failure(string() + "error while reading data");
  }
  return data;
}

vector<double> calculate_speeds(const vector<InputRecord> &data) {
  vector<double> speeds;

  speeds.push_back(0.0);
  for (std::size_t i = 1; i < data.size(); i++) {
    double delta_t = data[i].timestamp - data[i - 1].timestamp;
    double delta_s = data[i].location - data[i - 1].location;
    speeds.push_back(delta_s / delta_t);
  }
  return speeds;
}

void write_to_csv(const char *filename, const vector<InputRecord> &data,
    const vector<double> &speeds) {
  std::ofstream out(filename);

  if (!out.is_open()) {
    throw std::ios_base::failure(string()
        + "cannot open output file \"" + filename + "\".");
  }
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    out << data[i].timestamp << "," << speeds[i] << "\n";
  }
  if (out.bad()) {
    throw std::ios_base::failure(string() + "error while writing data");
  }
}

int main() {
  vector<InputRecord> data = read_from_csv("in.csv");
  vector<double> speeds = calculate_speeds(data);
  write_to_csv("out.csv", data, speeds);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.  I will try this out today.

Comment: Roland, I ran the code you provided (altering it to my needs) and it works like a charm.  I am truly thankful for your help, and it was great to be able to learn new stuff like this.