# Permutations Program Unable to Write to Array - Runtime Error

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, pointers

I'm working on a program that will display all possible permutations for an array, and then store the unique permutations in another array, however I am having issues with storing the unique permutations. I was going through my code and was getting a few errors because I had created the **uniquePermutations** variable and hadn't initialized. After trying to access the variable the program would crash so then I tried setting it equal to **nullptr** which helped.

So now when I use my **copyUniquePermutations** function (which is called in the **permute** function, it checks to see if the array is empty with **nullptr** and then if it is, we declare 3 new arrays, and set each spot equal to **NULL** so that we won't get any undefined behavior. Then next, I check to see if any spots are **NULL** so that we won't get to the **equalArrays** function which may cause issues and then we get to the assignment part which causes issues. Since we assigned **newArray[i]** to be **NULL** why does the computer say that it is having issues writing to this spot?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int permutations[] = { 2, 1, 2 };

void swap(int &x, int &y)
{
    int temp;
    temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}

bool equalArrays(int array1[], int array2[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (array1[i] != array2[i]) return false;

    return true;
}

void copyUniquePermutations(int oldArray[], int *newArray[])//This is the function that is causing issues
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (newArray == nullptr)
        {
            newArray = new int*[3];
            for (int j = 0; j<3; j++)
                newArray[i] == NULL;
        }

        if (newArray[i] == NULL || !equalArrays(oldArray, newArray[i], 3))
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                newArray[i][j] == oldArray[j];
        }
    }
}


void permute(int permutations[], int *uniquePermutations[], int l, int r)
{
    int i;
    if (l == r)
        copyUniquePermutations(permutations, uniquePermutations);

    else
    {
        for (i = l; i <= r; i++)
        {
            swap((permutations[l]), (permutations[i]));
            permute(permutations, uniquePermutations, l + 1, r);
            swap((permutations[l]), (permutations[i]));
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    int **uniquePermutations = nullptr;

    permute(permutations, uniquePermutations, 0, 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++)
        delete[] uniquePermutations[i];

    delete[] uniquePermutations;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using `std::vector`?

Comment: I need to store the different permutations as arrays and I thought you are not able to store arrays in vectors.

Comment: A `std::vector` is an array.

Comment: @brand5i2g -- Also, why are you not using `std::next_permutation()`?  Also usage of `std::set<std::vector<int>>` along with `std::next_permuation` makes this no more than 10 or so lines of code.

Comment: According to this post it says you can't because arrays are neither copy constructible or assignable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612273/correct-way-to-work-with-vector-of-arrays

Comment: @brand5i2g  -- *According to this post...* -- Use `std::array` instead of plain arrays.\

Comment: As opposed to using `std::set<std::vector<int>>`?

Comment: @brand5i2g -- When I state to use `std::array`, it is to thwart the claims of not able to store arrays in vectors.  `std::array` is copyable and assignable, and is the basic replacement for dumb plain arrays.  Otherwise, `std::set` stores only unique items, which is the container to use for your purpose, since there is no code to write to figure out if an item is a duplicate.

Comment: [A much simpler implementation](https://www.ideone.com/4Xujj5).

Comment: Wow that is way simpler, but the whole point of the exercise was to use recursion for the permutations. I will just try to use `std::array` and `std::vector` and see how that turns out.

Answer (score 1):

I think here you need to have `j` in `newArray[j]`

```
 for (int j = 0; j<3; j++)
                newArray[i] == NULL;
```