# Why can't I use vector with mpz_t in GMP?

Tags: c++, gmp

I don't know why this program goes wrong, because it is simple; however, if I can't use `vector` in GMP, the task will be so hard.

This is my code:

```
vector<mpz_t> elements;
  cout << elements.size() << endl;
  mpz_t a;
  mpz_init(a);
  elements.push_back(a);
```

This works well, but it is not as useful as `vector`:

```
// mpz_t b[10];
  // for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  //   mpz_init(b[i]);
  // }
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know what `mpz_t` is but it probably doesn't have a copy constructor?

Comment: yeah,i think this is the point too. because '=' can't use with mpz_t.so i solved it with the mpz_t *.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mpz_t` is a `typedef` to an array type. Instead of a vector of `mpz_t`, in C++ I would advise to either encapsulate `mpz_t` in your own class (that will also allow to manage memory) or use a vector of pointers to `mpz_t`.

As for the first option, [it already exists](https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-General) in the name of `mpz_class`.

> why i can't use vector with mpz_t in gmp?

`mpz_t` is a typedef to an array type. (From the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612273/correct-way-to-work-with-vector-of-arrays)): arrays are not copy constructible and not assignable, so you can't do `std::vector<int[1]>`.